# unable to set radio button in struts2

Tags: user-interface, struts2

I am not able to get the value of radio button selected in a page 
I have a JSP page as

```html
<body>
    <s:form action="/YYY" id="frmPersonalPage" name="frmPersonalPage" >
      <s:radio name ="radio" list="skillMasterData"></s:radio>  
   </s:form>
 </body>
```

This renders properly . In my struts.xml I have

```xml
<action name="YYY" class="com.tdi.atom.actions.CCC" method="showEditSkillMasterPage">
        <result name ="success">/jsp/modules/skillmap/createskillmaster.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In my action class I have this

```java
public class CCC extends BaseActionSupport {        
private ArrayList skillMasterData;  
public String   radio;
private ArrayList l1;
private ArrayList l2;
private ArrayList l3;

public ArrayList getSkillMasterData() {
    return skillMasterData;
}

public void setSkillMasterData(ArrayList skillMasterData) {
    this.skillMasterData = skillMasterData;
}

public String showEditSkillMasterPage()
{   log.info("at showEditSkillMasterPage");
    System.out.println("radio buttoneee : "+getRadio());//this is null
    setEditType("EDIT");
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String showListSkillMasterPage()
{
    SkillMasterDB pddb =new SkillMasterDB();
    JdbcHelper helper;
     l1 =new ArrayList();
       l2=new ArrayList();
       l3=new ArrayList();
       l1.add("asda");
       l1.add("rqwrq");
       l2.add("!@@##");
       l2.add("9087907");
       l3.add("./,/");
       l3.add("[][][]");
       skdto.add(l1);
       skdto.add(l2);
       skdto.add(l3);
       setSkillMasterData(skdto);
    return SUCCESS;
}
public String getRadio() {
    return radio;
}
public void setRadio(String radio) {
    this.radio = radio;
}
```

}

In BaseActionSupport class I have

```java
 public class BaseActionSupport extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
 private Map userSession;
 public UserDTO user; 
 public UserDTO getUser() {
 return mgr.getUser(); 
}
 public boolean isAdmin() {
 return mgr.isUserADMIN(); 
}
 public void setSession(Map session) { 
 userSession = session; mgr = new SecurityManager(userSession);
 }
 }
```

I just can't figure out why such simple code is not working. Else where very similar code works fine.

Comment: @RomanC Else where is dumny HelloWorld Struts2 Project where the radio button is working fine simply .

Comment: Could you specify what exactly is not working?

Comment: @RomanC only the radio button is not working .When I am displaying the button in the jsp its working . But in the action class I am not able to get the value . So I am not able to set the button

Comment: Initially you were not able to display it, right?

Comment: The value should be in the radio attribute after submit, did you debug it?

Comment: Why not you specify the interceptors of the action?

Comment: @RomanC I dont have interceptors , I was able to display the button , I was not able to get the value chosen in using property in jsp , also in the action the button was comming as null

Comment: What is the name of the jsp?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23147/discussion-between-minusseven-and-roman-c)

Answer (score 0):

There are some strange things in your code.

Assuming `CCC` and `YYY` are obfuscated names created only for posting them here (otherwise, you should use `CamelCase` with first letter capitalized for class names, like `MyAction`),

- you should respect `JavaBeans conventions`, then `userSession` should become `session`, because the accessors methods (getters and setters) should always respect the name of the private variable);
- `skdto` variable is not initialized nor defined in your `showListSkillMasterPage` method;
- I'm not sure if using `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` for radio button is good. You could try with a simple `ArrayList<String>`, like:

  ```
  public String showListSkillMasterPage() {
      SkillMasterDB pddb =new SkillMasterDB();
      JdbcHelper helper;    
      List<String> skdto = new ArrayList<String>();
      skdto.add("asda");
      skdto.add("rqwrq");
      skdto.add("!@@##");
      skdto.add("9087907");
      skdto.add("./,/");
      skdto.add("[][][]");
      setSkillMasterData(skdto);
      return SUCCESS;
  }
  ```
- Finally, you can test with `Firebug's Net module` what is going out of your page, check the radio parameter value now and after the edit to see what is going wrong now and how it will be going (hopefully) right later...

Comment: That's exactly what I did .Thing is even with hard coded Arraylist I am not able to set the radio button value , its coming as null . Whereas the same code in other cases is not . is there anyway to set the selected value of radiobutton on the session and get it from the session in the action class .

Comment: Believe me, the session is not involved here and it would be just another *variable* to handle in the equation... can you post the jpeg with the FireBug Net module output ? Parameters are in the "row" `POST`, and in the columnt `POST` (between `HEADER` and `COOKIES`)